# Plotting Standard Deviation Error for a Regression Line

Tags: regression, standard-deviation, standard-error, error

I have regression equation of the form: M=a+b*log⁡(SRL)
where a and b are derived constants.

I would like to plot error bars around the regression line, like so:
[image]

How do I calculate the error lines? I have the standard errors for the constants a and b; do I simply calculate M using +/- 1 standard error?

Comment: Please tell us what you want the "error bars" to represent.  Would they be simultaneous confidence intervals for the fitted values?  Prediction bands for individual values?

Comment: I want the error bars to represent 95% confidence intervals.

Comment: Please merge your accounts at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts so you can comment on and edit your question.

Comment: specifically [Account1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/174929/cjr) and [Account2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/174965/cjr)